# Bing Ads Api Programmatically Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bing, bing-api

How to get authorization code using [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-user-authentication-oauth-guide%28v=msads.90%29.aspx#authorizationcode) for a Web without browser login. I am using C#. I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-net-walkthrough-web-application.aspx) documentation.

`Redirect(authorization.GetAuthorizationEndpoint().ToString());`

redirected to this url

> https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=bingads.manage&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:52182/

And asking for password. How can I authenticate username and Password without using Browser? I want to make automate this procedure using C#.